# Add quotes to CSV through XQuery

Tags: xslt, xpath, xquery

I have a fragment of XML that I am trying to transform into a comma separated values line with each comma separated value being wrapped in quotes.

This is what I am trying to transform.

```
<xml>
<books>Harry Potter,The Hobbit,The Lord Of The Rings</books>
</xml>
```

This is what I want.

"Harry Potter","The Hobbit","The Lord Of The Rings"

I have tried this

```
let $args := $context//xml/books
let $lines := tokenize($args, ',')

return
string-join(concat("'", $lines, "'"), ",")
```

Unfortunately I get this error. Can anyone help?

*A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second argument of concat() ("Harry Potter","The Hobbit","The Lord Of The Rings")*

Comment: Beware of quotes in the original text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are concatenating a string-serialized version of your sequence of tokens with the beginning and end quotes. Instead, you need to iterate over your tokens, and apply quotes to each of them.

```
string-join(
  for $l in $lines
  return concat('"', $l, '"'), 
",")
```